# Comparing strings in lists using python

Tags: python

I have two lists which i have picked from a column of a dataset from the server

```
Keywords =(('Nike shoes',),('Adidas shoes',),('Levice Jeans',),('adidas jersey',))

Chats = (('Nike shoes have an offer',),('They are at a discount'),
         ('Nike shoes are the best',),('They have other offers as well',),
         ('They have introduced new shoes which are awesome',))
```

Both lists are in exactly the same format as above

I want a third list which will store all the common words from the keywords list.

```
o/p - list3 = ('Nike Shoes')
```

I have tried various things but found errors like "list values should be integers,not tuples"

Comment: you don't have  two lists. You have two tuples.

Comment: more precisely you have tuples of tuples, but there's an issue here: `('Nike shoes have an offer',),('They are at a discount'),`. The second one isn't a tuple. so you have tuples or mixed tuples/strings... Or is it a typo? please share your data/code with a [mcve]

Answer (score 0):

The given data is tuple because they are from DB. So, you might need to change your data first. (Of course there are different ways.)

```
Keywords =(('Nike shoes',),('Adidas shoes',),('Levice Jeans',),('adidas jersey',))

Chats = (('Nike shoes have an offer',),('They are at a discount',),
         ('Nike shoes are the best',),('They have other offers as well',),
         ('They have introduced new shoes which are awesome',))

# Make them lists because it's easy to use in your case
keywords = [keyword[0].lower() for keyword in Keywords]
chats = [chat[0].lower() for chat in Chats]

# Store all the common words into list3
list3 = []
for keyword in keywords:
    if any(keyword in chat for chat in chats):
        list3.append(keyword)

print(list3)
# ['nike shoes']
```

You don't need `keyword[0].lower()` part for current data but it might be helpful to convert all your text into lowercase for comparison.

Answer (score 0):

You can just do this:

```
Keywords =(('Nike shoes',),('Adidas shoes',),('Levice Jeans',),('adidas jersey',))

out=[]


Chats = (('Nike shoes have an offer',),('They are at a discount',),
     ('Nike shoes are the best',),('They have other offers as well',),
     ('They have introduced new shoes which are awesome',))
for i in Keywords:
    for j in i:
        for k in Chats:
            for l in k:
                if j in l:
                    out.append(j)
out1=tuple(out)
print(out1)
```

This is gonna give you same output as you need.